# Java Regix trying to read substring from text file

Tags: java, text

I am trying to read certain useful information from a text full of rubbish but it some sensor reading. I am losing a lot of useful information from this code

like 'NH3 leve
l is: 9.9977'

there has to be something more efficient than this can someone please help me with it

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sensorclean {
final static String Array[] = new String[1000];
    static int g = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

File file = new File("C:/Users/Omar/Desktop/datatest.txt");
try {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String newline=ignoreComments(line);
if(newline!=null)
    Array[g] = newline;
    g++;
}

for(int i =0; i<Array.length;i++){
    if(Array[i]!=null)

    {

        Array[i] = Array[i].trim();

    System.out.println(Array[i]);

    }
}

}

 catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
private static String ignoreComments(String line) {
String result_line=null;

int upto=line.indexOf('#');
int upto1 = line.indexOf('ë');
int upto2 = line.indexOf('~');
int upto3 = line.indexOf('€');
int upto4 = line.indexOf('?');
if((upto!=0&&upto>0)&&(upto1!=0&&upto1>0)){
result_line=line.substring(1, upto4);
System.out.println("here");
}
else{
if(upto<0 && upto1<0 && upto2<0 && upto3<0 ){
result_line=line;
}/*else{
result_line="";
}*/
}
return result_line;

}
}
```

my sensor reads temperature and stores it in a .txt file. but it adds rubbish in it
I am working on a java that extracts useful information from it

this is a sample of what is in the file

> *ë~^€}3¢@iw4R#}3¢@iw
>               CO level is: 101.0831, CO2 level is: 375.2046, NH3 leve
>   l is: 9.9977  ?~O€}3¢@isGR#
>                                  -mac:0013A20040691673,-time:Wednesday, 12/11/14 -
>    14:06.56, E~G€}3¢@isGR#}3¢@is
>                                       TEMP: 51.9354, HUMIDITY is: 9.6129, bat: 63%*
>
> ~_€}3¢@isGR#}3¢@is
>                            CO level is: 106.1330, CO2 level is: 374.7616, NH3 leve
>   l is: 86.7625  ?~O€}3¢@if:R#
>                                   -mac:0013A20040691666,-time:Wednesday, 12/11/14
>   - 14:09.20, é~I€}3¢@if:R#}3¢@if
>                                        TEMP: 280.0000, HUMIDITY is: 17.7677, bat:
>   96%
>   I~^€}3¢@if:R#}3¢@if
>                            CO level is: 128.8912, CO2 level is: 375.6922, NH3 leve
>   l is: 9.9977  E~O€}3¢@iw2R#
>                                  -mac:0013A20040691677,-time:Wednesday, 12/11/14 -
>    14:12.11, ?~H€}3¢@iw4R#}3¢@iw
>                                       TEMP: 20.3225, HUMIDITY is: 19.3161, bat: 87
>   %
>   ?~^€}3¢@iw1R#}3¢@iw
>                            CO level is: 101.0831, CO2 level is: 375.1160, NH3 leve
>   l is: 9.9977  ?

this rubbish is not always the same its changing

and here is my current code

Comment: You might want to read the site FAQ before posting as it will tell you how to properly format your code so that it is in fact readable.

Comment: Is `NH3 leve` on the first line of the file and `l is: 9.9977` on the second? Or is there a space in between?

Comment: no its a line difference sorry, i couldn't find a way to post it the way it was

Comment: It kinda looks like you have binary and ASCII data mixed in you're file. Try looking at the data in a hex editor and seeing if the rubbish looks like timestamps, lengths, or message IDs.

Answer (score 0):

it is not regex based, still:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        boolean isRubbish = false;
        for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                if (!isRubbish) {
                    res.append(tmp).append(' ');
                } else {
                    isRubbish = false;
                }
                tmp.setLength(0);
            } else if (isRubbish(c)) {
                isRubbish = true;
            } else {
                tmp.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}

private static boolean isRubbish(char c) {
    return "#^}@?".indexOf(c) > -1;
}
```

Comment: ya see thats the thing when i modified the code to this

 `private static boolean isRubbish(char c) {`
     `return c == '#' || c =='^' || c =='}' || c == '@' || c == '?'||c=='ë'||c=='~'||c=='€'||c==''||c=='¢'||c==''||c=='é'||c=='';`
 `}`

my out put was something like this

3iw4R3iw CO level is: 101.0831, CO2 level is: 375.2046, NH3 level is: 9.997

they are on one line which is good but it took out the rubbish but the rubbish has valid numbers and characters I don't need those

Comment: its still not giving out clean text